# D3 extend Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'NumberValue'.ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I have an array of objects of this shape:

```
export interface Candlestick {
  openTime: number;
  closeTime: number;
  open: number;
  close: number;
  high: number;
  low: number;
  baseVolume: number;
  tradesCount: number;
  isClosed: boolean;
}
```

I have full control over this data because I return it from the server myself, there are no undefined values, there were string values but I converted them to numbers just in case. I try to create a linear scale like so

```
  const yAccessor = (d: Candlestick) => d.high ?? 0;
   const yScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, yAccessor))
```

The thing is whatever I did I keep getting those errors:
When i hover over data:

```
Argument of type '[undefined, undefined] | [number, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<NumberValue>'.
  Type '[undefined, undefined]' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<NumberValue>'.
    The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'IteratorResult<undefined, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<NumberValue, any>'.
        Type 'IteratorYieldResult<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<NumberValue, any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<NumberValue>'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'NumberValue'.ts(2345)
(parameter) data: Candlestick[]
```

When I hover over yAccessor:

```
Argument of type '[undefined, undefined] | [number, number]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<NumberValue>'.
  Type '[undefined, undefined]' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<NumberValue>'.
    The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'IteratorResult<undefined, any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<NumberValue, any>'.
        Type 'IteratorYieldResult<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<NumberValue, any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<NumberValue>'.
            Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'NumberValue'.ts(2345)
const yAccessor: (d: Candlestick) => number
```

I don't understand what the problem is here, why is it complaining about the undefined values? Also is it parsing this data or does it rely on types?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to debug if there is actually no undefined values in your coming data?

Comment: Related: [*"Error: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'?"*](/q/55963129)